# setTemplatePath within plugin in Cakephp3

Tags: cakephp, plugins, cakephp-3.0

How do I set the template path for a view relative to a plugin? This is what I'm trying to do:

```
$view = new View();
$view->setLayout('Kuroi/EvzDuser.email'); // <-- this works
$view->setTemplatePath('Kuroi/EvzDuser.Plugin'); // <-- this doesn't work!!!
$view->set('html',$html);
$view->set('lang',$this->lang);
$layout=$view->render('email_register');
```

CakePhp is looking for my template file (email_register.ctp) in the wrong directory:

> Confirm you have created the file:
>   "Kuroi/EvzDuser.Plugin/email_register.ctp" in one of the following
>   paths:
>
> /Applications/AMPPS/www/eventspritz.com/evz_2019/src/Template/Kuroi/EvzDuser.Plugin/email_register.ctp

My template file (email_register.ctp) is in the following directory:

/Applications/AMPPS/www/eventspritz.com/evz_2019/plugins/Kuroi/EvzDuser/src/Template/Plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, sorry, I found the solution. For anyone interested:

```
$view = new View();
$view->setLayout('Kuroi/EvzDuser.email');
$view->setTemplatePath('Plugin');
$view->set('html',$html);
$view->set('lang',$this->lang);
$layout=$view->render('Kuroi/EvzDuser.email_register');
```